# "ssl_preread" is not working in NGINX

Tags: nginx, webserver

I am trying to implement "ssl_preread" in my nginx. My nginx is compiled with "--with-stream_ssl_preread_module" this module.

I mentioned "ssl_preread on;" in server directive of nginx.conf. But i am getting below error.

nginx: [emerg] "ssl_preread" directive is not allowed here in /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:43

I am following below doc.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.html

Comment: I guess you you try to use it in `http` section instead of `stream`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, I used this inside server tag only.

Comment: And your `server` block is inside `http` block

Comment: @AlexeyTen, yes . it's inside http block.

Comment: Why do you even want ssl_preread directive for http server?

Comment: Can you show your config?

Comment: @alexeyTen for which directive we can use ssl_preread?

Comment: None. You don’t need it for https seerver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Compile with both modules

> --with-stream
>
> --with-stream_ssl_preread_module

2. Create a stream block outside http block

> ```
> stream {
>     upstream app {
>         server IP1:Port;
>       server IP2:Port;
>     }
>
>     map $ssl_preread_server_name $upstream {
>         default app;
>     }
>
>     server {
>         listen PORT;
>
>         ssl_preread on;
>         proxy_pass $upstream;
>     }
> }
> ```

This worked for me. Let me know if this works for you too

Comment: I am stuck with this now, and I just cannot get it working. I'm getting this error "nginx: [emerg] "stream" directive is not allowed here in /usr/local/nginx/conf/dynamic-certificates/lowtraffic01.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test failed"

Any ideas to what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe U need to update Nginx to lastest version. 1.10 I meet this error too, but 1.18  the config is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a late answer. I had the following issue when installing `nginx 1.14` from CentOS 8.3 repo.

```
The error was: MisconfigurationError('Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.\n\nnginx: [emerg] unknown "ssl_preread_server_name" variable\nnginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed\n',)
The nginx plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: MisconfigurationError('Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.\n\nnginx: [emerg] unknown "ssl_preread_server_name" variable\nnginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/
nginx.conf test failed\n',)
```

I fixed it by upgrading the very latest `nginx-1:1.20.0-1.el8.ngx.x86_64`, following this URL

http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#RHEL-CentOS